# How to detect Json property sent twice

Tags: c#, json

Given json:

```
{ "x":"a", "x":"b" }
```

When deserializing into a C# dynamic object, an object is created with property `x` with value `b`. No `JsonReaderException` is thrown, even though the same property is sent twice.

Is there a way to detect if property is sent more than once in the json string?

Comment: JSON.NET has token reading functions.  You could use those to compare each token to previously read tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why no `JsonReaderException` is thrown is because duplicate keys are *valid* in JSON.
A quick and dirty workaround would be to have a counter that gets incremented every time `X` property on your class gets set. If it is `> 1` then you know.

```
public class Test 
{
    private string _x;
    private int xCounter = 0;
    public string X 
    {
        set
        {
           if(xCounter > 1) throw new Exception("DUPES");
            xCounter++;
           _x = value;
        }
        get
        {
           return _x;
        }
    }
}
```

This will obviously fail if you try to set `X` again after deserialization.